# Should [tag:loop] be consistent with StackOverflow ([tag:loops])?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

While suggesting an edit for the  for the [loop](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop) [tag-wiki](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/20052), I realized that its equivalent on StackOverflow is [loops](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loops). Should we rename it to be consistent with SO? It would obviously need a tag synonym for the singular, and my suggested edit would need to be updated slightly, to refer to the new tag rather than the current one.

Comment: BTW, I do think this tag is useful, since loops represent some of the hairiest programming problems that many SharePoint devs may face.